# What are these green rulers along the top and side of this Illustrator document?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, guides

I recently opened an Illustrator file made by my employer's previous graphic designer and found that it had these rulers along the side that have the appearance of guides, but didn't go away when I hid guides, smart guides, or rulers. They're not a problem and I don't need to recreate them, I'm just wondering if anyone has any idea what they are because I've never been them before.

[image: Illustrator document with green rulers on top and left side]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Those are called Video Rulers

They can be turned on/off under View -> Rulers -> Video Rulers

---

You can also turn on/off various settings for these rulers based on the artboard options.

Go to Window -> Artboards

Click on the dropdown to select Artboard Options...

Under Display there are more options (checkboxes) for the video rulers like showing video safe areas.

Answer (score 0):

The document has been set up be optimised for creating video assets using the Video And Film Document profile.

[image: document profile dialogue]

More info here: https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/files-templates.html

Comment: The page you link to for more info does not mention these rulers?